# Writing a temporary compiler to write a compiler in the new language

Tags: compiler-construction

What is the term used to refer to when you create a new language and write the compiler for that language, in a different one, then once the 'temporary' compiler is well-developed, rewrite it in the same language using that temporary compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get into the new language, its called "bootstrapping"

You don't need the temporary compiler to handle the whole language, just enough to let you get started with the first version of the real compiler. Then keep adding features and using them in the next rev.

Answer (score 5):

The term for that is "[bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29)".

Answer (score 4):

**Q:** "If one needs a compiler for language X to obtain a compiler for language X (which is written in language X), how did the first compiler get written?"

**A:** [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))